# How to get the Ref value in a test with Vue 3 Composition API

Tags: unit-testing, testing, vuejs3, vue-composition-api

I have a v-if rendering in my component that is link to a ref in the setup method.
How can I test the rendrering in my testing script.
Example:

In the component:

```
<div v-if="isCovid" class="covid"/>

 setup() {
    const isCovid = ref(true);
}
```

In the test component (I try this but dont work, the test received true):

```
 it('do not render covid waring when its false', () => {
    const wrapper = mount(TicketHeader,{
      data(){
        return { isCovid: false}
      }
    });
    expect(wrapper.find('.covid').exists()).toBe(false)
    });
```

Comment: did you get an answer for this?

Answer (score 0):

If you are using the `setup()` method this is what counts. In the test you then use `data()` which AFAIK doesn't work if you use `setup()`.

One small side note there, do you return `isCovid` so it is accessible in the
template?

I don't think you can modify a `ref` that you create in `setup()`. You'll probably need to provide something as a prop which you then access there. I just found this with an example:
https://lmiller1990.github.io/vue-testing-handbook/composition-api.html#the-component